# Solve $\log_2( \log_{1/2}(\vert x \vert - 1 )) > 0 $

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

I am new to logarithmic inequalities.
How to find the solution set for this inequation:

$$\log_2( \log_{1/2}(\vert x \vert - 1 )) > 0 $$

I tried by taking two cases:

$$ \log_2( \log_{1/2}( x - 1 )) > 0$$
and
$$ \log_2( \log_{1/2}(- x - 1 )) > 0$$

Then by solving them, I got $  x \in \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right) $

Sorry, it was a silly calculative error

I got $  x \in \left(\frac{-3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right) $

Is this the correct way? Can anyone provide a good or a robust way?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum I've edited now, please don't down vote.. I was stuck at this question.

Comment: I see your edit and I removed my downvote.

Comment: That's helping :) What about others who downvoted?

Comment: Given that you alredy recieved a very good answer, I wouldn't worry too much about the downvotes.

Comment: @5xum You're very encouraging, thank you so much

Comment: @5xum Unfortunately, the accepted answer is utterly wrong. And so is the other one. I'm surprised they even got upvotes and that the question got downvoted and closed.

Comment: @RaviPrakash Have updated my answer, and it now agrees with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2(log_0.5(%7Cx%7C%E2%88%921))%3E0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the equality that $\log_ab=c\Longleftrightarrow a^c=b$

Therefore, we have \begin{align}\log_2(\log_{1/2}(|x|−1))&>0\\
\log_{1/2}(|x|−1)&>2^0\\
\log_{1/2}(|x|−1)&>1\\
0<|x|−1&<\left(\frac12\right)^1\\
0<|x|−1&<\frac12\end{align}

We have to flip the sign when raising $\frac 12$ to a power, as larger powers mean smaller values. We must also ensure that the inside of the logarithm is always gresater than $0$ as we cannot take a logarithm of a negative number.

Now we can solve this as we would with a normal absolute value question. We split it into two halves and solve each half.

When $|x|=x$:

\begin{align}0&<x-1<\frac 12\\
1&<x<\frac 12 + 1\\
1&<x<\frac 32\end{align}

When $|x|=-x$:

\begin{align}0&<-x-1<\frac 12\\
1&<-x<\frac 12+1\\
1&<-x<\frac 32\\
-1&>x>-\frac32\end{align}

So, we can conclude that $$x\in\left(-\frac32,-1\right)\cup\left(1,\frac 32\right)$$

Comment: Why everybody here after exponentiating inequality with base 1/2 does not change the inequality sign? $5>3$, but $(1/2)^5<(1/2)^3$

Comment: @egreg Thanks, didn't spot that, have updated my answer and it now agrees with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2(log_0.5(%7Cx%7C%E2%88%921))%3E0)

Comment: @lioness99a Now it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Properties used here:

> 1. If $a > 1$, then $\log_a M > b \iff M > a^b$
> 2. If $0 < a < 1$, then $\log_a N > b \iff N < a^b$

Applying the first property, we see that $\log_2M > 0$ means $M > 2^0 = 1$.  So you need to have $\log_{1/2}(|x| - 1) > 1$.

Now apply the second property:  $\log_{1/2} N > 1$ means $N < (1/2)^1 = 1/2$.  So now you need $|x| - 1 < 1/2$.

Recall that anything you take a logarithm of (regardless of the valid base) must be positive.  So you must also have $|x| - 1 > 0$.  (This domain restriction also implies that $\log_{1/2}(|x| - 1)$ must be positive, but this is already enforced by the earlier fact that we must have $\log_{1/2}(|x|-1) > 1$.)

Comment: Do you really think that when $B > 1/2$, we have $\log_{1/2} B > 1$? Say, $B = 1$, do you think $\log_{1/2} 1 > 1$?

Comment: @egreg how you got $ x = 9 $ ?

Comment: @egreg I agree. What is the correct way?

Comment: @egreg, thanks, fixed.

Comment: @ZainPatel, fixed

Comment: @RaviPrakash, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Still technically wrong: “implies” should be “if and only if”.

Comment: @egreg, fixed${}$